# Notation $e^{\pm \pi \cdot i}$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

I am confronted with the equations as $(1-t)=(t-1)e^{\mp\pi i}$, or $(1-e^z)=e^z(1-e^{-z})e^{\mp\pi i}$ and alike. I am wondering what this means. Isn't it true that $e^{\pi i}= -1 =e^{-\pi i}$?

Best wishes

Comment: I don't get what your question is. In the first equation we get: $$(1-t)=(t-1)(-1)=(1-t) \checkmark$$ and the second equation: $$(1-e^z)=e^z(1-e^{-z})(-1)=(e^z-1)(-1)=(1-e^z) \checkmark$$ Both of these equations are true. Is your problem understanding why the author of this "problem" decided to include $\pm$ even though $e^{-\pi i}=e^{\pi i}=-1$?

Comment: Yes. It looks really awkward to write the number -1 as $e^{\mp \pi i}$, therefore I would think that there is maybe a different meaning as well...

Comment: Maybe it is just there to remind that $e^{ix}$ is a periodic function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're right -- $e^{\pm\pi i}$ cannot really be anything else than a rather convoluted way of writing $-1$.

Unless you're dealing with a single author who has a strange idiosyncratic tic (always a possibility) the point must be to *remind* the reader that algebraic negation of complex numbers corresponds to geometric rotation by half a turn around the origin. Whether this is a relevant or helpful point to make of course depends on the context -- but perhaps the next step of the computation is to merge the $\pm \pi i$ into a different $e^{\text{something}}$ factor that's already present in the expression?

Comment: Thank you for your wonderful answer. One situation is as follows: The author considers some loop integral $\int_{1}^{z}(1-t)^{\alpha}f(t)dt$, where $f(t)$ is a very ugly function. Then he wants to evaluate the integral and writes $1-t=(t-1)e^{\mp \pi i}$.... Does this provide enough context to get a clue what the author had in mind?

Comment: @HastiMusti: Not really, sorry. My best guess is that it must be what happens to the $e^{\mp\pi i}$ _afterwards_ that must be the motivation for writing it in that way. For now my recommendation would be to read on with an open mind and see if it turns out to be useful later on to have written the negation in that form.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 1):

$$ e^{\pi i}=\cos\pi+i\sin\pi=-1$$
$$e^{-\pi i}=\cos(-\pi)+i\sin(-\pi)= -1 $$

The equations are same by putting these values.